# Multi-tenancy in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am starting to work on evaluation of Spring Cloud DataFlow.
One of the considerations I have is ability to execute Tasks or Streams in context of a particular tenant.  This is especially true if we need per-tenant configuration of task triggers.

Do you know of any way to support this or in general support multi-tenant Spring Cloud Data Flow environment?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I understand your comment and slightly encouraged by this.   My real need is in a SaaS environment, how do you provide capabilities of SCDF on a per-tenant basis.   This includes dashboard, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of background before we get into the details.

SCDF is a lightweight RESTful (Sring Boot) application, which happens to include orchestration mechanics to deploy, launch, or operate on data pipelines made of stream/task applications (aka: Spring Boot applications).

For high-availability, fault-tolerance, resiliency along with multi-tenancy requirements, SCDF delegates it and relies on the platform where you run it.

Let's dive into the details now.

When you deploy streams/task from SCDF to Cloud Foundry, you will deploy them to an [Org/Space](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html) boundary, which happens to be accessible by folks who have access to it. Extending that, when you use the [SCDF Tile for PCF](https://network.pivotal.io/products/p-dataflow), you'd be able to [create a service-instance](https://docs.pivotal.io/scdf/1-2/managing-service-instances.html#creating) for SCDF from a particular Org/Space combination, so it naturally comes with the said boundary. The boundary then becomes an environment for project/team specific streams/tasks to run without collisions - thus preserving the tenancy attributes.

Similarly, when you deploy streams/task from SCDF to Kubernetes, you'd have the boundary defined by ["namespaces"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) and the access-control.